# F5 BIG IP - ajax POST with HTTP response truncated

Tags: ajax, post, jmeter, f5

Jmeter 2.12.

I used a scenario fully functional in front of a reverse proxy Apache. Recently we 've replaced the reverse proxy with the F5 BIGIP technology and now my scenario hangs.

The problem is for a particular ajax POST request the HTTP response is truncated : i receive a 200 OK but the HTML content is not full (no html tags for example). When i post the same request with Firefox the full content is ok. 
Note that i don't receive the http header Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

In this case what can be the difference between Firefox and JMETER ? 
Anyone have an idea on how could i get the full html response ?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: The response is not very large by any chance? Running into the JMeter max response size?

Comment: try by giving `Firefox User-Agent` in JMeter `HTTP Request` using `HTTP Header Manager`. The server might be responding based the client.

Comment: i've already checked : it's not a reponse size problem, neither a user-agent. (with firefox the request returns 38kb, with JMETER 2kb)  Also in my scenario the precedent ajax POST runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on the settings on your F5 and what exactly you mean with "response is truncated" and "no html tags". Do you get the correct response but the html tags are stripped out? or is the response just truncated so you i.e. only get the first n bytes?

The best way to find out what is actually going wrong is to use something like fiddler in between and try to find the real difference between the responses, especially regarding the response headers (Content-Length, Transfer-Encoding, etc).

When you found the actual difference please post here so we can help you further.

On a sidenote, by any chance do you have some custom coding on the f5 (iRules) which react to different user-agent settings?

Answer (score 0):

Given you send identical requests you should be receiving identical responses.

Use JMeter's [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request details, or even better compare requests which are being sent by Firefox and JMeter using a lower level network sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), detect the differences and configure JMeter accordingly to send the same request(s) as Firefox does.

The other reason might be JMeter truncating large response, by default JMeter displays "only" first 10 megabytes in the View Results Tree listener, if this is the case - you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up - it will suppress response truncation and you will be able to view the full response data.

Alternative way of setting the property is passing it via `-J` command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jview.results.tree.max_size=0 ....
```

References:

- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: i've already compared the two requests : the only difference is the user-agent. In my precedent upper comment  i've told about size.